# Magento 2: How to include JS on the product page?

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, product-page

I'm trying to get a custom js on the product page, I'm using Magento 2, what's the page I need to edit to do that? I've already tried to create a `local.xml` into **/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/yume/Magento_Catalog/layout** , and add the code inside , but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For example, We have our folder structure of current theme:

[image]

We should focus four files:

> Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml 
>   Magento_Catalog/templates/product/js.phtml

- Add new template to call our jQuery plugin. That helps us to include our js on product detail page only.

**Layout**

```
#app/design/frontend/Boolfly/yume/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="custom.js" as="custom.js" template="Magento_Catalog::product/js.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**Template:**

```
#app/design/frontend/Boolfly/yume/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/js.phtml

    <script>// <![CDATA[
        require([
            'jquery',
            'hello'
        ], function ($) {
            $('.product-info-main').HelloWorld();
        });
        // ]]>
    </script>
```

> app/design/frontend/Boolfly/yume/web/js/custom.js

- We can create our own custom jQuery plugin.

  ```
  define('jquery', function($) {

      $.fn.HelloWorld = function() {
          alert('Here');
      }

      }(jQuery)
  );
  ```

> app/design/frontend/Boolfly/yume/requirejs-config.js

- Create a RequireJS configuration file.

  ```
  var config = {
      map: {
          '*' : {
              'hello' : 'js/custom'
          }
      }
  };
  ```

Clear Magento Cache and run static content deploy:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

We can read more here how to create custom Javascript: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

Comment: thank you for your time @Khoa TruongDinh , that worked fine , what about if I need to insert a js library only on the home page ?

Comment: You can see here:http://www.boolfly.com/magento-2-slider-with-owl-carousel/. We can add Require js in cms home page.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh the above link has expired can u give any other reference thank u...

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh can we use custom.js and requirejs-config in the module Magento_Catalog ?