# Add javascript library only on the category page?

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, template, requirejs

I'm using magento 2 and I'm trying to insert a javascript library into into my category page. I only need it so I can stick my sidebar , so I don't need them also on other pages , what is the right file to edit so I can add the libraries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simple need to override **`catalog_category_view.xml`** file into your theme.

code for `catalog_category_view.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <head>  
        <script src="js/custom.js"/>
    </head>
    </body>
</page>
```

**custom.js** file path is `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/custom.js`.

Call your custom.js file inside theme **list.phtml** file with below code,

```
<script>
    require(['jquery','js/custom']);
</script>
```

Without need of declare `requirejs-config.js` file you can directly call inside your category page.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh , how do I call it , if the name is custom.js ,  with this code require(['jquery','js/jscolor']); ?

Comment: i have updated my answer. i have to rename js file.

Comment: thank you for your time @Rakesh , can I use the same for the product page right ?

Answer (score 5):

If we take a look at this topic [Magento 2 Include js on the product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114327/magento-2-include-js-on-the-product-page), we can see how to include js on the product page only. We can include javascript library on category page in the same way.

Our folder structure:

[image]

We should focus four files:

-`Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` and `Magento_Catalog/templates/category/js.phtml` - Add new template to call our jQuery plugin. That helps us to include our js on category page.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="custom.js" as="custom.js" template="Magento_Catalog::category/js.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Template: using RequireJs to call our custom js or js library.

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
    require([
        'jquery',
        'hello'
    ], function ($) {
        $('.product-info-main').HelloWorld();
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

-`app/design/frontend/Boolfly/yume/web/js/custom.js` - We can create our own custom jQuery plugin.

```
define('jquery', function($) {

        $.fn.HelloWorld = function() {
            alert('Here');
        }

}(jQuery)
);
```

-`app/design/frontend/Boolfly/yume/requirejs-config.js` - Create a RequireJS configuration file.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*' : {
            'hello' : 'js/custom'
        }
    }
};
```

Clear Magento Cache and run static content deploy: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`