# Magento 2 load external script in my custom page

Tags: magento2, requirejs, external, requirejs-config.js, meqp2

I want to add an external script to my store. I have added the script in my phtml file and it is working fine. But I want to follow the magento EQP validation.
Here is my working code
my layout xml

```
<head>        
  <script type="text/js" src="https://test.test1.com/js/v1/test.js" src_type="url" />
</head>
```

This is my phtml file:

```
<div><?php echo $block->getHtmlSnippet();  ?></div>
<div class="test-wrap">
    <div class="test-inner-wrap">        
        <script>
            Test.test1({              // Test.test1 is the function definted in https://test.test1.com/js/v1/test.js
                token: '<?php //echo $block->getToken();  ?>'
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have changed it as follows (using require js function)

Phtml file

```
<div><?php echo $block->getHtmlSnippet();  ?></div>
<div class="test-wrap">
    <div class="test-inner-wrap">          
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": { "Vendor_Module/js/modtoken": {
                    "token" : "<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getToken()));  ?>"
                 } }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            testjs:'https://test.test1.com/js/v1/test.js'
        }
    }
};
```

This is js file app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/modtoken.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "testjs"
], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    return function (config) {        
        Test.test1({
                token: config.token
            });
        console.log(config.token);        
    }    
});
```

But the above method is not working. Please help and suggest a method to call this file using require js.

Comment: When you see requirejs-config.js do you see your code mapped for hipsjs?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: When you view source your website there is a link to javascript like _requirejs/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js. If you open that file do you see the code that you wrote in requirejs-config.js

Comment: Sorry no link with requirejs-config.js. But another file with name /frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js exist

Comment: it should be there, please share view source screensht of all js files list

Comment: I found that file in view source. But I didn't see the code wrote in require js file.

Comment: Which means that the file is not rendered, can you share the location of the requirejs-config.js file?

Comment: Or try to clear the static content, var cache, view processed etc.. all the folders and check in incognito window

Comment: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js - This is the path of the require js file.

Comment: Try placing in view/frontend path SO it will be parallal to web

Comment: I want this js only in one page. For Ex: baseurl/test/testa/ For that page requirejs-config.js is not loading .
http://i.prntscr.com/X3PsS6S8RWeULQOzdJDmSg.png 
It is loading for home page

Comment: You can add via xml similar how shown here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114327/magento-2-how-to-include-js-on-the-product-page