# How to add custom js file for PDP page in magento 2

Tags: jquery, product-view, magento2.2.6

I wish to include custom js file in PDP page in magento 2.

I wish to do some action while product has some options. Please provide me a solution to add custom js in PDP page

Comment: You can refer this link.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114327/magento-2-how-to-include-js-on-the-product-page

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps

1) create `Magento_Catalog` folder under `app/design/frontend/Custom/default`

2) create a `layout` folder and copy `catalog_product_view.xml` file from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout` and paste inside it

3) open that XML file, in head tag paste your custom js file like

Make sure your custom js file should be in `app/design/frontend/Custom/default/web/js`

4) run this commands `php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush`

check in view page source your file will be there